# Definition of Distinct eigenvalue clarification?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm solving a problem where I am given the eigenvalues of a matrix $A$ and need to solve for the determinant of $A$. I know that if my matrix is diagonalizable I can find the determinant of $A$ by multiplying the eigenvalues together. However, I am given these eigenvalues: $-2, 3, -\frac23, 4, 4, 4, \frac12, \frac12$. As you can see, there are multiple repeats. I am given the fact that $A$ is an $8\times8$ matrix. I was just wondering that if I have repeated eigenvalues does that mean that I don't have $8$ distinct eigenvalues but instead $5$ eigenvalues?

Comment: The determinant is still the product of all eigenvalues, with multiplicities.

Comment: Even if the matrix is not diagonalisable, it can be put intriangular form, with eigenvalues on the diagonal. The theorem you mention on computing the determinant for a diagonal matrix, is also valid for a triangular matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your matrix is diagonalizable we have 
$$
A=P\Lambda P^{-1}
$$
where
$$
\Lambda=
\scriptsize{
\begin{bmatrix}
-2  &    0 &   0 &   0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0  & -\frac23 &   0 &   0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0  &    0 & \frac12 &   0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0  &    0 &   0 & \frac12 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0  &    0 &   0 &   0 &   3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0  &    0 &   0 &   0 &   0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
 0  &    0 &   0 &   0 &   0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
 0  &    0 &   0 &   0 &   0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}}
$$
It follows that
\begin{align*}
\det{A}
&= \det(P\Lambda P^{-1}) \\
&= \det(P)\det(\Lambda)\det(P^-1) \\
&= \det(P)\det(P^{-1})\det(\Lambda) \\
&= \det(PP^{-1})\det(\Lambda) \\
&= \det(I)\det(\Lambda) \\
&= \det(I\Lambda) \\
&= \det(\Lambda) \\
&= (-2)\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)(3)(4)(4)(4) \\
&= 64
\end{align*}
so the multiplicity of each eigenvalue does matter!